# java - Server accepting large amounts of long-lasting client connections

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I have a small server that accepts large amounts of long-lasting connections from clients. In my current situation the server creates a new Thread for every accepted connection that listens for incoming data and returns the appropriate response. It is essential that incoming data from the client is handled as quick as possible.

This situation is not optimal when the server has around 1000~10000 connections. I found an example where a Connector class is used to manage the different SocketChannels.

[Connector example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/Ping.java)

But I don't think this is applicable for my situation. Does anyone have suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest you to use NIO frameworks like Netty or Grizzly. They provide you a simple way to handle thousand of connection and threat them with a limited number of thread with events.